# Value inside loop doesn't change

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain me how to change **template.portNumber** value ?

```
var template = {
  portNumber: null,
  stuff: ""
}

myfunc(template, 3);

function myfunc(template, count) {
  var ports = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var portNumber = i + 1;
    ports[portNumber.toString()] = template;
    ports[portNumber.toString()].portNumber = portNumber;
  }
  console.debug(JSON.stringify(ports, null, 4));
  return ports;
}
```

**Result:**

```
"{
    "1": {
        "portNumber": 3,
        "stuff": ""
    },
    "2": {
        "portNumber": 3,
        "stuff": ""
    },
    "3": {
        "portNumber": 3,
        "stuff": ""
    }
}"
```

**Expected:**

```
"{
    "1": {
        "portNumber": 1,
        "stuff": ""
    },
    "2": {
        "portNumber": 2,
        "stuff": ""
    },
    "3": {
        "portNumber": 3,
        "stuff": ""
    }
}"
```

Sorry for the stupid question but i really stuck with it. Same code works well in python.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/222163 (read around closures in JS)

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra This is not a closure issue.

Comment: Ah, fuzzy morning brain... you're totally right @Juhana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `template` object is passed by reference, so all the items refer to the same object. It ends up looking a little like this:

```
template = {portNumber: 3, stuff: ""};
return {ports: {1:template, 2: template, 3: template}}
```

You need to [clone the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object), and then set it.

```
var template = {
  portNumber: null,
  stuff: ""
}

myfunc(template, 3);

function myfunc(template, count) {
  var ports = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var portNumber = i + 1;
    ports[portNumber] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(template));
    ports[portNumber].portNumber = portNumber;
  }
  console.debug(JSON.stringify(ports, null, 4));
  return ports;
}
```

Also, you don't need to manually stringify a numerical key, it's done automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Your array ends up having three references to the same object so each time you mutate it the change is visible in all array elements.

Writing `ports[0].port = "99"` will in other words change also `ports[1].port` because `ports[0]` and `ports[1]` are the very same object.

You need to create a copy of the object instead...

Answer (score 3):

The reason all array object are reference type so point to only one instance.

Try using constructor function like this.

```
var template = function(portno, stf){
  this.portNumber = portno;
  this.stuff = stf;
}

myfunc(template, 3);

function myfunc(template, count) {
  var ports = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var portNumber = i + 1;
    ports[portNumber.toString()] = new template(portNumber , template.stuff);
  }
  console.debug(JSON.stringify(ports, null, 4));
  return ports;
}
```

Comment: `new template(portno, template.stuff);` should be `new template(portNumber, template.stuff);`. Also, since you're passing `portNumber` to `template`, you can remove the line `ports[portNumber.toString()].portNumber = portNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference problem.

```html
console.log(myFunc(template, 3));

function myFunc(template, count) {
  var ports = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var portNumber = i + 1;
    ports[portNumber.toString()] = {portNumber:null, stuff:""};
    ports[portNumber.toString()].portNumber = portNumber;
  }
  // console.debug(JSON.stringify(ports, null, 4));
  return ports;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because template variable in your function holds the reference of the template object outside your function.
Try this:

```
 function myFunc (template, count) {
var ports = {};
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var portNumber = i + 1;
    var tmplt = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(template));
    tmplt.portNumber = portNumber;
    ports[portNumber + ''] = tmplt;
}
return ports;
    }
```